# How to open the Isar inspector

Tags: android, windows, flutter, dart, flutter-isar

I have been trying to find a way to open the Isar database inspector.

Does anyone know how to open the inspector?

Answer (score 3):

1. Set `inspector:true` in Isar.open()

```
Isar.open(
      schemas: [...],
      directory: dir.path,
      inspector: true,
    );
```

2. Download and install the isar inspector [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1sXvfywjLQ5-y8W8PgPIYw3RhWhBDWUKX?usp=sharing) for windows and [here](https://github.com/isar/isar) for mac
3. Look for this link in the logs `ws://127.0.0.1:63001/addadada=/` copy it.

```
flutter: ╔════════════════════════════════════════╗
flutter: ║          ISAR CONNECT STARTED          ║
flutter: ╟────────────────────────────────────────╢
flutter: ║ Open the Isar Inspector and enter the  ║
flutter: ║ following URL to connect:              ║
flutter: ╟────────────────────────────────────────╢
flutter: ║   ws://127.0.0.1:63001/addadada=/      ║
flutter: ╚════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

4. Open the isar inspector and paste this link.

Comment: inspector property is `true` default

Answer (score 0):

According to ISAR homepage, there are now only an executable to access the inspector, with the link generated in debug output, just for Mac (https://github.com/isar/isar) and in issues discussion, #snhmehta posted a Windows version (https://github.com/isar/isar/issues/90).
Just remember to enable the inspector with `inspect:true` in your application.